# How to Implement Custom Membership and Roles in Oracle Database

Tags: c#, oracle, custom-membershipprovider

How to implement Custom Membership and Roles in Oracle DB. are we need to write the overload for the Membership Function ? If yes then How ?

Where is the Database Schema for Membership and roles for oracle.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643456/how-do-i-use-asp-net-membership-provider-with-oracle

Comment: I know but no solution there too..

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom membership provider. When you create a class which inherits from membershipprovider it should implment all the right classes automatically.
You can also override the membershipuser if you want to add some custom features.

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider
```

I would use the custom membership provider just as a container so i would use another class to handle all the database calls and such.

```
    public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        return ProfileManager.GetPassword(username);
    }
```

In ProfileManager for instance:

```
    public static string GetPassword(string username)
    {
        if (!username.Contains("custom\\")) return String.Empty;

        MijnGazelleEntities container = new CustomEntities();
        Users gebruiker = container.Users.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Email == username.Replace("mijngazelle\\", String.Empty));
        string password = gebruiker != null ? gebruiker.Password : String.Empty;

        container.Connection.Close();
        return password;
    }
```

Comment: You are correct. But the problem is i am gonna implement in Oracle. I dont have any stored procedure like we have in SQL predefined for Membership and roles. SO how will that gonna work ?

Comment: Instead of using EF you can use something like Microsoft Enterprise Library, you can connect to any database you'd like i guess.
Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx and maybe this is helpful too: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/enterpriselib.html